Combinatorial proof by sign-inversing involution
I want to prove the following identity by using a sign-inversing involution.

Let $n,m \geq 0$, $\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}=(-1)^m
 \binom{n-1}{m}$.

Appraoch:
I know that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}=0$, and I know that the RHS of the identity in question is the amount of fixed points of the involution.
My Problem is that the summation on the LHS goes to $m$.
If $m=n$, then we get the already mentioned $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}=0$ (note that $\binom{n-1}{n}=0$).
So I thought I could do the other two cases:
Let $m<n$, in that case $\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{n}{k}$ would represent the sum of $k$-elemental subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$.
And then $\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}$ would represent the number of even $k$-elemental subsets minus the amount of odd $k$-elemental subsets but only up to the number $m$.
I somehow need to find a involution $\phi$ that describes this identity. Especially the sets $\binom{n}{m+1}$,...,$\binom{n}{n}$ have to be fix points under this involution. And the involution has to "pair" even sets with odd sets.
I did think about the following function (that is a modification of the involution used to prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}=0$):
For  $A \in 2^{\{1,...,n\}}$ define,
$\phi(A)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} A\setminus \{1\}, & 1 \in A \text{ and } |A|\leq m \\
         A \cup \{1\}, & 1 \not\in A \text{ and } |A|\leq m  \\ 
 A, & |A|>m
\end{array}\right.$
But I am stuck here and don't know how to continue (or if my approach is correct).

This duplicate is relevant.

Prove it by induction on $m.$

Your approach looks fine. But $\phi$ is not an sign-inversing involution. You could define $\iota(A):=A \triangle {1}$. $\iota$ does work, for except when $|\iota(A)|>m$. This case happens when $A$ has exactly $m$ elements and does not contain $1$. So we need to count those cases. But these are the subsets of ${2,.,,,n}$ with exactly $m$ elements, i.e. $\binom{n-1}{m}$. Since those sets have $m$ elements, we get $(-1)^m$.

You are almost correct. The domain of $\phi$ should not be all of $2^{[n]}$ (where $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$). Instead, since this is an alternating sum only involving sets up to size $m$, the domain and range of $\phi$ should only be subsets whose size is at most $m$. Here is the correct definition of $\phi(A)$ for all $A$ in this domain:
$$
|A|\le m\quad \implies \quad \phi(A)=
\begin{cases}
A\setminus \{1\} & \text{if }1\in A
\\
A\cup \{1\} & \text{if }1\notin A\text{ and }|A|\le m-1
\\
A & \text{if }1\notin A\text{ and }|A|=m 
\end{cases}
$$
This is a valid involution, because you can check that $\phi(\phi(A))=A$ for all $A$ with $|A|\le m$. Furthermore, whenever $\phi(A)\neq A$ (the first two cases of the piecewise definition), then $\phi(A)$ and $A$ will differ by one element, so $|\phi(A)|$ has an opposite parity from $A$, as required by a sign-reversing involution. Therefore, the alternating summation $\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k \binom nk$ is equal to the number of fixed points.
Not that $A$ is a fixed point of $\phi$ if and only if $1\not\in A$ and $|A|=m$. There are $\binom {n-1}m$ subsets fitting this definition, and each comes with a sign of $(-1)^m$ in the signed count. We conclude the whole summation is $(-1)^m\binom{n-1}m$.
